# Unable to post data or send a file using axios and form-data

Tags: node.js, express, axios, form-data

I am trying to post data from my nodejs app to a an endpoint.

I tested sending some data to that endpoint using Postman and all works fine, I got the posted data and all got printed to the console.

but I am always getting empty post data at my endpoint when sending from my nodejs using axios.
here is my code:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const axios = require('axios');

function send_to_test() {
    const endpoint = 'http://localhost:5000/test';
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('string_var', 'some string');
    form.append('integer_var', 100);
    axios.post(endpoint, form, { headers: form.getHeaders() }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
    });
};
```

and here is my endpoint (I am using express js server):

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({
        status: 'success'
    });
});
```

Unable to get this working, please advise and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a form parser at the your endpoint. You can make use of formidable. code for reference:

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    if (err) {
         return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }
   res.json({
       status: 'success'
    });
}
```

I hope it gives you better picture!

Comment: isnot `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); app.use(express.json());` equivalent to your code? I have these middlewares set already.